# my button to scroll images does not work on swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I wanted to make a small carousel type app with swift but I have a problem with my code

in my viewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func changeImage(_ sender: Any) {
        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "d6e6f07c-7412-4889-9e78-182d1b7f815c.jpeg")
    }
}
```

but when i click on the button to scroll the images, his show me

> {Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)} in xcode.

Comment: check if that image is in your resources.xcassets?, and remove ".jpeg" from name

Comment: If your resource name is correct then check your image view connection to storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` means that there was an assertion failure in your code.

I guess that the UIImageView doesn't connected with `xib` or `Storyboard`